# LIMIT(SELECT...) IN SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is this syntax allowed in sql (any DMS):

SELECT rows from table limit (select count(*) from table where value = 7)

In other words, is having a select statement within a limit allowed? Why or why not?

Comment: Why would you ever need that?. `SELECT rows FROM table WHERE value = 7` will already limit the rows to the ones with the value = 7. It can't possibly return any more than that, which would mean it can't be more than `COUNT(*)`. `LIMIT` is designed for cases where you have many rows that match the WHERE condition but you want to restrict the results to a set number of rows.

Comment: Then your question should be asking how to do that instead, and should be about the specific DBMS you're already using, rather than asking if *any DMS* allows some random SQL.

Comment: Without knowing the specific DBMS the interviewer was asking about, or at least knowing what they were looking for, it's impossible to tell whether you were right or not. If you weren't sure, you should have asked the interviewer at the end of the interview, when they ask if you have any queestions for them. I've done so, and both found out I was right and that I was wrong (and learned from an explanation of why). I've also learned that my understanding of the question was wrong, and had an opportunity to show I knew the answer to the real question that was being asked and gotten the job.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is not allowed in MySQL, not without using dynamic SQL to build the `LIMIT` clause.  On MySQL 8+, we can try the following using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable WHERE value = 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres supports this syntax.  For example:

```
create table n as
    values (1), (2) ;

select *
from (values ('a'), ('b')) v(x)
limit (select count(*) from n)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e584536a08cd1b263150193f76aa6c52) is a db<>fiddle.

However, most databases require that the value for `limit` (or the equivalent construct) be defined at compile time.

Comment: @CSStudent . . . I have no idea what you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not allowed in any database engine. `limit` requires fix values not varying one **(applicable in sqlite and postgresql)**

```
SELECT rows from table limit (select 10)
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=hCPJDw6E0z)